# DataFrame.duplicated() error in function recursion TypeError: duplicated() got multiple values for argument 'keep'

Tags: python, dataframe, recursion

I am using Python 3 on Jupyter notebook.

**Use case:**

Process all the records of an excel file.

**Problem**:

Duplicate records against the column Login id in excel while the underlaying processing can not process a Data set with duplicate records for a login id. So trying to process the records in batches by filtering and creating sub data sets for the duplicate records using recursive function.

**Test data set**:

[image: Test data set]

Python code:

```
# process withdrwal of duplicate enteries with recrursive function


def withdrw_user_balance(withdraw_records):
#create new data frame using the 
duplicateRowsDF = withdraw_records.duplicated(['Login'], keep = "first")
duplicateRowsDF.head(10)

#remove duplicates from the original data frame
withdraw_records.drop_duplicates(['Login'], keep='first', inplace=True)

#process withdraw request for the non-duplicated row data frame
# processWithdraw()

#update the status
for row in withdraw_records.itertuples():
    withdraw_records.at[row.Index, 'status'] = 1

# write to excel the processed data frame
# writeExcel(withdraw_records)

# clear the object withdraw_records
withdraw_records = None

# check the size of new dataframe, if greater then 0, recruse the withdrw_user_balance() to find more duplicate records in the current
# else return
if duplicateRowsDF.size > 0:
    print("recrusion called")
    withdrw_user_balance(duplicateRowsDF)
else:
    return True;
```

The next code is to execute the recursive function:

```
# import the excel file
withdraw_records_excel = pd.read_excel("batch-withdraw-duplicate-login.xlsx")
withdraw_records_excel.tail()

withdraw_records_excel.size
withdrw_user_balance(withdraw_records_excel)
```

Out put:

```
recrusion called
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-bae5054c7199> in <module>
  4 
  5 withdraw_records_excel.size
----> 6 withdrw_user_balance(withdraw_records_excel)

<ipython-input-5-2ecdc243bfb2> in withdrw_user_balance(withdraw_records)
 27     if duplicateRowsDF.size > 0:
 28         print("recrusion called")
---> 29         withdrw_user_balance(duplicateRowsDF)
 30     else:
 31         return True;

<ipython-input-5-2ecdc243bfb2> in withdrw_user_balance(withdraw_records)
  4 def withdrw_user_balance(withdraw_records):
  5     #create new data frame using the
----> 6     duplicateRowsDF = withdraw_records.duplicated(['Login'], keep = "first")
  7     duplicateRowsDF.head(10)
  8 

TypeError: duplicated() got multiple values for argument 'keep'
```

I think that the error is because the function parameters are **pass by reference** in python so the data frame some how keeps the reference of previous function call hence the DataFrame.duplicate() method is throwing error.

To fix that, I have nullify the DataFrame object as **withdraw_records = None** after processing, but no help.
Note that I am a starter in python so I may have wrong information on the types and object reference.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I was able to fix the issue in the code.
rather than

```
#create new data frame using the 
duplicateRowsDF = withdraw_records.duplicated(['Login'], keep = "first")
```

I need to write:

```
duplicateRowsDF = withdraw_records[withdraw_records.duplicated(['Login'], keep = "first")]
```

It will return the the sub-DataFrame of duplicate records in each call to the function which can be passed as parameter in the consecutive recursive function call to create batches of unique records.

I have used the pixidust debug tool to debug this program which helped a lot in identifying the issue. Following this link:
[Use pixidust debugger with Jupyter notebook](https://medium.com/codait/the-visual-python-debugger-for-jupyter-notebooks-youve-always-wanted-761713babc62)